# VirtualBox abnormal behavior when mouse focus from iMac Maverick to vm running Debian wheezy

Tags: osx, virtualbox, debian

I am experimenting this really **annoying** behavior.

I never had this problem with other platform combination.  In this combination:

- Hardware OS Host: iMac Maverick
- Oracle VirtualBox 4.3.2 r90405
- Vm Debian Wheezy.

When I unfocus the mouse from the vm I normally can interact with any iMac window.  As soon as I click in the vm, then either one of these scenario happen:

- some text becomes selected, in an app like (xterm, chrome, ...) or 
  any window opened in the Debian XWindow running environment.
- worse, one of the Debian XWindow gets resized or moved, I loose the 
  window title bar, and I have to play with the maximize, minimize, ...
  to get back the apps window to the correct position and size.

The only solution to avoid this behavior is to do, before interacting with the Debian Xwindow environment, the following:

- click to the VirtualBox surrounding window to get the vm be the active window from iMac context, and only then interacting with the apps windows in the vm without any side effect.

Since I am switching between the host and the vm many times a minute, every now and then, I unfortunately forget this trick and here we go again... I am considering hosting this vm on Windows7, where I do not seem to have the same problem.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: @jordanm, the mouse is capture by both environment. I guess this is ok, as mouse integration.  Do you have a recommendation ?

Answer (score 2):

Did you install the VirtualBox Guest additions into this VM? This generally needs to be done after the VM has been setup. The installation of this software is an extra and is OS specific, to the OS of the guest VM itself. There are directions on installing it here:

- [Chapter 4. Guest Additions](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html)

The directions are OS specific so make sure that you pick the appropriate OS that your guest is using. Once installed this will allow your mouse to freely move between the guest's window and the host's desktop without any capturing of focus.

Comment: Many it was not done after all, let me try it.

Comment: I am pretty sure it was installed since I tested sounds with youtube videos before and I am assuming that without GuestAdd, it would of not work.  Cannot tell if the Guest Additions was related to my mouse problem, I finally installed VM 4.3.6 r91406, this fixed it.  I do not like to just upgrade, blindly, but this problem was becoming a nightmare.

Comment: This problem seemed to disappeared but it is actually still there.  It is less frequent which leads me to conclude that there might be a bug somewhere.